# Fine-tuning NLP models

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, nlp, transfer-learning

In computer vision, if we don't have a large training set, a common method is to start with a pre-trained model for some related task (e.g., ImageNet) and fine-tune that model to solve our problem.

Can something similar be done with natural language processing problems?  I have a boolean classification problem on sentences and don't have a large enough training set to train a RNN from scratch.  In particular, is there a good way to fine-tune a LSTM or 1D CNN or otherwise do transfer learning?  And, if we want to do classification on sentences, is there a reasonable pre-trained model to start from?

Answer (score 2):

This paper might be useful....

https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146

Comment: http://nlp.fast.ai/classification/2018/05/15/introducting-ulmfit.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider few-shot learning approaches, recently found guys that practice such approaches for their information extraction models, claiming you will need somewhere between 8 training examples. But it depends on the cases you are looking to train and the expected satisfied precision.
https://huggingface.co/knowledgator